# Some Matrix equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

I wonder how to construct such Matrix that in such form:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
f(x) & g(x)\\
0& h(x)\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Satisfying $f,g,h$ are not homogeneous,

case 1: $A^2\neq\begin{bmatrix}d_1(x) & 0\\ 0 & d_2(x)\\\end{bmatrix}$, but $A^3=\begin{bmatrix}d_1(x) & 0\\ 0 & d_2(x)\\\end{bmatrix}$ , for some $d_1(x),d_2(x)$

case 2: $A^kA'=A'A^k,k\geq3$,$A^2A'\neq A'A^2$

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: $A^2 = \left [\begin{matrix} f^2 & g(f+h)\\0 & h^2\end{matrix}\right]$, and $A^3 = \left [\begin{matrix} f^3 & g(f^2 + fh +h^2)\\0 & h^3\end{matrix}\right]$. It doesn't take much to get your answer from there.

Comment: Good idea. Actually, I thought case 1 could be a special case of case 2, but I still cannot figure out case 2

Comment: Case 1 is supposed to be a hint for solving case 2, I think. One thing you might want to think about is that a product of functions can be $0$ even though the individual functions are not $0$.